# How can i call my resteasy service remotely?

Tags: javascript, hibernate, maven, wildfly, resteasy

I have implemented a resteasy service runs on Wildfly server, which communicates with a mysql database.  The frontend runs on an apache server and sends xhr requests to the rest service via javascript.  Through port mapping I was able to call the javascript frontend in remote, but not to call the backend.  Any solution?

Comment: There's not really enough information here to go on.

Comment: can you show some code?